# How to get checkbox state for each row in table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the state of a checkbox in each row within a table, I'm succesfully retrieving one of the values of the columns from the table, but when it comes to the column that holds the checkboxes elements, I cannot get the state.

Here is the code I am using to iterate through the table for those rows selected:

```
$.each($("input[name='query']:checked"), function () {
    var data = $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)');

    var Name = $(data).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var Value = $(data).find('td:eq(2)'); //This is the checkbox column

    console.log('Name: ' + Name + ' - Value: ' + Value );
});
```

And here is one sceenshot of the table itself:

[image]

The catch here is, if the users selects a row (ticks the checkbox in the first column) and then tries to save the changes, I need to get the value in the **Name** column and then the state of the checkbox in the **Value** column.

Finally, here is what the console is printing using the code mentioned above:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find `checkbox` in column and check for `checked` property

Change

```
var Value = $(data).find('td:eq(2)');
```

to

```
var Value = $(data).find('td:eq(2)').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked");
```

or

```
var Value = $(data).find('td:eq(2) input').prop("checked");
```

Comment: Yeah, this is working right now, thank you so much :)

Comment: @JoseAndresValenciaAcosta Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var Value = $(data).find('td:eq(2)');
```

to

```
var Value = $(data).find('td:eq(2) input').prop("checked");
```

or

```
var Value = $(data).find('td:eq(2) input').is( ":checked" )
```

Comment: @JoseAndresValenciaAcosta You're right, I left out the input selector. Try now.

Comment: @j08691 Your code works too now that you added the input selector, thank you